# blank screen after kernel upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, grub, opensuse, dual-boot

I am running ubuntu 10.10 with catalyst ati drivers which I installed from the amd website. Recently I took some updates which included a new kernel. I cannot boot into ubuntu. The screen shows ubuntu 10.10 thing but after that the it goes blank. I am using suse grub loader.

Comment: First thing you should do is to look back at your previous questions and accept answers that work for you. Your 20% is too low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the new kernel doesn't have the modules that comes with your proprietary driver and fails to use your configuration files. If you still have the boot menu that comes with a default Ubuntu installation then you can choose "Recovery mode". In the next menu choose to boot into safe mode, and if Ubuntu asks if you want to create a new configuration file just allow it to do so. There should be other ways to generate new configuration (like deleting some dot files) but I just know this way.

Then when everything is OK reinstall the graphic driver.

Edit: to boot into recovery mode see the question [How do I prevent GRUB from using/starting any graphical UI?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4027/250)

Comment: I added ubuntu to suse grub manually because it did not appy automatically. How do I add recovery mode to the grub.

Comment: @Vaolter: see the link in my question

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably have to reinstall your drivers since the drivers rely on the kernel headers. Reboot into recovery mode and then blacklist the fglrx module. Then you can reboot into your console and reinstall the drivers.

Fglrx drivers have always been a pain since it makes it ridiculous to upgrade your kernel.

Comment: I dont have recovery mode on my grub how do I manually add it.