# Arch Linux not booting after system update

Tags: arch-linux, boot, upgrade, udev, pacman

After running a system update `pacman -Syu` with the testing repo not commented, my computer no longer boots. It shows the udev loading, then shows a black screen with a cursor blinking in upper left. I cannot type, or switch `tty`. What logs should I look at for help? When Looking at verbose boot, it says

> /bin/sh can't access tty

and I can't type anything at the prompt.

Comment: Is there a boot option for safe mode, single user, or failsafe?  If you can get to the kernel command-line, try adding single or init=/bin/sh to the command-line.

Comment: Look at [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4027/250) and see if you can still boot into single user mode

Comment: Are you using AMD proprietary drivers?

Answer (score 7):

This is how I fixed this problem :

I've booted into an arch installation CD and mounted my root partition under /mnt/arch.

```
mkdir /mnt/arch
mount /dev/sda4 /mnt/arch
```

I then ran the following commands:

```
cd /mnt/arch
mount -t proc proc proc/
mount -t sysfs sys sys/
mount -o bind /dev dev/
```

Depending on your file system, you may need to bind-mount different partitions and folders. Don't forget to check if the boot partition is properly mounted:

```
ls /mnt/arch/boot
```

If the boot folder is empty, you need to find the partition `lsblk -f` and mount (let's use sda1 as boot partition in this example:) `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/arch/boot`

I then issued the chroot command and configured my network:

```
arch-chroot . /bin/bash
dhcpcd eth0
```

I'm not sure if all of these commands are required, but I didn't feel like continuously rebooting/chrooting, so I did them all at once and it fixed the issue we both were having:

```
pacman -Syy
pacman -Syu
pacman -S udev
pacman -S mkinitcpio
mkinitcpio -p linux
reboot
```

Remove the CD or USB drive and ta-da! Now, I'll be honest and admit that I don't fully understand this fix. Some of the posts also suggested doing a “pacman -S linux”, however that was not necessary for me.

Comment: OMG you literally saved my life, thank you so much!
The mounts were a bit different for me (I had to do `-o bind` mounts to properly point subfolders from the encrypted LUKS partition and I had to mount a different  nvme boot partition to /boot), but after correctly mounting the stuff, it worked like charm. You are a hero!

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you can still [boot into single user mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4027/250) if the problem is only with the display. Otherwise you boot a live CD, mount your drive(s) and then `chroot` to gain access to your system.

After that the first thing you should do is to check `/var/log/pacman.log` to see what may have broken your system. I would suspect an update to `xorg` or the kernel to cause problems like this. What to do next depends entirely on the package to be fixed.

Please forgive if I'm mistaken, but perhaps you missed the on-screen message that Pacman output when you performed the upgrade. Those are generally important, especially to a rolling release distro like Arch. To quote the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Upgrading_packages):

> It is essential that users read all information output by pacman and use common sense.

Comment: Thanks, I am not able to boot into Single User Mode, but i will look at the pacman log.