# Arch Linux stuck booting

Tags: arch-linux, boot, shared-library, thinkpad

Since I updated my Arch system with `sudo pacman -Syu` I am not able to boot into X anymore. All I see is a warning about the unsupported brightness interface. This was shown before, is a known bug and not the reason of the problem.

I am able to start a CLI session by `cmd+alt+<f2-f6>` but I am not able to login with my username and password.
If I boot into single user mode I am not able to start the terminal session because of this error:

`/bin/sh: error while loading shared libraries: libncursesw.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Before I mess around with `chroot` like suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10617/arch-linux-not-booting-after-system-update?newreg=b9ac6019eb17470883c077db07eeb377), I would like to know if there is a possibility to fix the missing shared library error.

I am using GNU GRUB version 2.02^beta2 on a ThinkPad L450.

Comment: *Never* [pacman -Syy $package](http://gist.io/5660494), it breaks your system. Use a live medium, mount your partitions under `/mnt` and `pacman -r /mnt -Su`.

Comment: @jasonwryan I did not update a package but the whole system.

Comment: Apparently not: otherwise your shell would not be looking for an older curses library...

Comment: @jasonwryan Can you provide an answer with a more detailed description to your solution or at least a link please?

Comment: There isn't more to it: boot from a live disk, mount your necessary partitions and run the update pointing to your mounted `/`.

Comment: got "not enough disk space" although I got 5gb on my root partition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30282/discussion-between----and-jasonwryan).