# Debian (Gnome): unable to login

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, login

I installed Gnome, and unable to login, as only root is set, and disabled, I think after reading on the Internet.

Now how do i get back to the command line, at least so I can deal with that and fix my issues from there? I am unable to bypass the Gnome login screen.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing `CTRL+ALT+F1` should get you to console TTY. You can login from there, and add a regular user for yourself, etc. If that doesn't work, you'll have to boot in single-user mode. Just follow the [steps here](http://nixcraft.com/linux-software/246-debian-boot-into-grub-single-user-mode.html) and then add user using the syntax below:

```
useradd -m -s /bin/bash userName
passwd userName
```

where `userName` is the name of the user to create. You can then reboot into normal mode if you booted in single-user mode or switch consoles to graphical console by hitting `ALT+F7`

Comment: You'll need `control-alt-F1` to get back to the console.

Comment: @Shadur, duly noted, I was messing with formatting and deleted the beginning of the sentence. I edited the answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Links about single user mode on this site: [How do I run a command as the system administrator (root)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root); [more specific Grub instructions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4027/how-do-i-prevent-grub-from-using-starting-any-graphical-ui/4030#4030),